# What to do with a big bag of roasted fava beans

Tags: beans, middle-eastern-cuisine

I wanted to get some healthy snacks for my family, so I bought a big bag of roasted fava beans (lightly salted + sunflower oil), but they turned out to be pretty unexceptional.

I wouldn't want them to go to waste, so - does anyone have any ideas on how I could either upgrade the taste or use them in a recipe?

The only thing that comes to my mind is to blitz them and use instead of chickpeas for making falafels, but... I really bought a lot, so I'd appreciate some more variety.

Comment: They might work in some sort of snack mix.  (Chex mix, for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Given that they are already roasted, I would **not** expect them to work well in falafels, etc.

Upgrade the taste depends on you and/or your family's tastes. I'd reach for lime, ginger, garlic. Other folks would whip out the chili powder and salt. I might do some black pepper. Finely grated to the point of being powdered cheese. Nutritional yeast. Balsamic vinegar. Take a small test batch and add things **you** like to them, or things other people in your family like. Cinnamon-sugar for the sweet direction, perhaps. Do up some caramel and treat them like popcorn.

If you have multiple bags/packages, all but one sealed, of this disappointing-but-nutritious snack, consider donating the sealed packages to a food pantry and learn to try a little bit before going hog-wild on new things you haven't taste-tested. If it's one huge bag, that's not an option.